# Google Sheets - Repeat Number Sequence in Column

Tags: google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets and want to repeat a number sequence in a column for cycle days. However, I need it to check against another column to verify if it is "closed." If the day is closed it is to leave the cell blank or input 0 and continue the pattern in the next cell below.
**=if(D4="Closed","",if(C3=6,1,(C3+1)))**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8tHM.png)

Comment: It would be good to see a sample of what you are trying to produce. Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

in C1 : put 1, in C2 put :

```
=if(D2="closed",,mod(row()-1-countif(D$1:D1,"closed"),6)+1)
```

[image]